# Columns used in stored procedure

Tags: sql

How to find if a column is used in any insert, update or delete statements in a stored procedure. I used a system query, but was not accurate. Can we check it manually in sql management studio or any query is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easier way is to use ***RedGate SQL Search***.

But, you can build a query using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES and the ROUTINE_DEFINITION if you feel like.

edit:

You can use this

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_DEFINITION 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%YOUR COLUMN %' 
    AND ROUTINE_TYPE='PROCEDURE'
```

or if you have more than one column with same name in database, you can use this.

```
select DISTINCT p.name
from sys.procedures p   
    INNER JOIN sys.sql_dependencies d on p.object_id = d.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t on t.object_id = d.referenced_major_id
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES R ON R.ROUTINE_NAME = p.name
WHERE R.ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%YOUR COLUMN %' AND t.name = YOURTABLE
```

But, I think you should use Search SQL

Comment: I'll try, but can I have some sample query as its pretty urgent?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and let you know tomorrow.