# Query to find out the stored procedure depending on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have to change the name and the datatype of a column of a table. I have about 150 stored procedures in the database, out of which about 25 refer to the same column. I need a query that can find the name of all the stored procedures which are dependent on this column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine table referenced in a view in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308252/determine-table-referenced-in-a-view-in-sql-server) (the answer is same for both views and stored procedures).

Comment: It should actually be linked to http://stackoverflow.com/q/4812962/1100940 (Text search in stored proc SQL Server) which is, by far, a better fit to the question asked.

Comment: See also [Columns used in stored procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3609001/90527).

Comment: A proper search will parse your procedures into words, filter out comments, and return a distinct list of procedures containing the column names. This [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421565/script-to-determine-if-a-stored-procedure-is-readonly-or-read-write/9424798#9424798) will do exactly that.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I use this query:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(M.object_id), M.*
FROM sys.sql_modules M
JOIN sys.procedures P
ON M.object_id = P.object_id
WHERE M.definition LIKE '%blah%'
```

Obviously you'd have to substitute "blah" for the name of your column.

Comment: You're also going to want to check if any views are using the column, and include a list of stored procedures that depend on those views. Then you also should check which stored procedures are dependent on this list of stored procs, and which depend on those, etc. Usually the call chains don't go deeper than 2-3 levels so this shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Note that this only determines which procedures contain string "blah" -- they don't necessarily reference your column. Still, it's the best start you have without third-party tools.

Comment: The problem in this query is, it doesn't include table name. I have multiple table with the same coloumn name.

Comment: if you add a condition like " and M.definition like '%blahtable%' you woud filter only those stored procedures that contain both terms. If you can guarantee the definitions have both column name followed by the table name (select blah from blahtable) you could change the condition to " like '%blah%blahtable%' " and so on...

Comment: Comments could be a problem too

Answer (score 4):

Try this 1
From Sp

```
SELECT Name as [Stored Procedure Name]
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%getdate%' order by Name
```

From Table

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%EmployeeID%'
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

    As you know there is no way to query what fields are referenced by a function or stored procedure.
    The closest we can get is an approximation.
    We can tell which tables are referenced and what fields might possibly be referenced by those tables.

    For example, if you have "*CreatedDate*" referenced by the "*Person*" table and you join to the "*Order*" table (which also has a "*CreatedDate*" field), it will find a “*false-positive*” match to "*Order.CreatedDate*" when you were only looking for "*Person.CreatedDate*".

    Searching the *Text* of the object's script for field names is unfortunately the best we can do for now.
    The good news is, it won’t miss identifying fields that are actually used.
    If anything it might pull in more than what *were* used (due to shared field names or commented out code).
    The *only* exception would be dynamic SQL, as Tables are not linked to Object Scripts if they are embedded in a dynamic string.

**Workaround:**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ft_Schema_Column_Script]
(
    @ScriptName nVarChar(128) = '%',
    @TableName  nVarChar(128) = '%',
    @ColumnName nVarChar(128) = '%'
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT @@SERVERNAME[ServerName], DB_NAME()[DatabaseName],
           SS.name[ScriptSchemaName], SO.name[ScriptName],
           SO.type_desc[ScriptType], 
           TS.name[TableSchemaName], T.name[TableName], C.name[ColumnName],
           UT.name[ColumnType], C.max_length[MaxLength],
           C.precision[NumericPrecision], C.scale[Scale],
           C.is_nullable[Nullable],
           C.is_identity[IsIdentity],
           C.column_id[Ordinal],
           EP.value[Description]
      FROM sys.sql_modules as M
      JOIN sys.objects     as SO--Script Object.
        ON M.object_id = SO.object_id
      JOIN sys.schemas as SS--Script Schema.
        ON SS.schema_id = SO.schema_id
      JOIN sys.sql_expression_dependencies D
        ON D.referencing_id = SO.object_id
      JOIN sys.tables as T
        ON T.object_id = D.referenced_id
      JOIN sys.schemas as TS--Table Schema.
        ON TS.schema_id = T.schema_id
      JOIN sys.columns as C
        ON C.object_id = T.object_id
      LEFT JOIN sys.types AS UT--Left Join because of user-defined/newer types.
        ON UT.user_type_id = C.user_type_id
      LEFT JOIN sys.extended_properties AS EP
        ON EP.major_id = C.object_id
       AND EP.minor_id = C.column_id
       AND EP.name = 'MS_Description'
     WHERE  T.name LIKE @TableName  ESCAPE '\'
       AND  C.name LIKE @ColumnName ESCAPE '\'
       AND SO.name LIKE @ScriptName ESCAPE '\'
       --Use RegEx to exclude false-posotives by from similar ColumnNames.
       --  (e.g. Ignore the "ModifiedBy" field when matching on "Modified").
       --  Use C.name instead of @ColumnName to further reduce false-positives.
       AND M.definition LIKE (  N'%[ ~`!@#$\%\^&*()+-=\[\]\\{}|;'''':",./<>?]'
                              + C.name
                              + N'[ ~`!@#$\%\^&*()+-=\[\]\\{}|;'''':",./<>?]%'
                             ) ESCAPE '\'
)
GO
```

**Test:**

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
   SELECT * FROM dbo.ft_Schema_Column_Script('ScriptName', DEFAULT, DEFAULT) as C
   SELECT * FROM dbo.ft_Schema_Column_Script(DEFAULT, 'TableName',  DEFAULT) as C
   SELECT * FROM dbo.ft_Schema_Column_Script(DEFAULT, DEFAULT, 'ColumnName') as C
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
```

Test the example above to see if it's good enough to meet your needs.

**Results:**

Example output when running this function searching for the Column Name "*Created*".
[image: Example of running the function searching for the Column Name "Created".]


It searches Stored Procedures (Sprocs), User-Defined-Functions (UDF's), Triggers, but *not Jobs*.

The cool thing is:
This not only searches for Columns referenced by Scripts,
*but* also Scripts referenced by Columns (or Tables)!

Answer (score 0):

Search in Stored Procedures Only:

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID),
object_definition(OBJECT_ID)
FROM sys.Procedures
WHERE object_definition(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%' + 'BusinessEntityID' + '%'
```

Comment: what is the problem? add some description to your question!!

Answer (score 0):

-- Search in All Objects

SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID),
definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%' + 'BusinessEntityID' + '%'